# How to use format files in a different directory

Tags: pdftex, format-files

I have successfully built my own format file from a large preamble.  I can successfully use it when I `pdflatex` with the `.tex` in the same directory as the `.fmt`, but how do I access that `.fmt` file if I want to compile a pdf from a different directory?

The first line of my `.tex` file reads `%&pre` in order to use my format file `pre.fmt`.  I tried `%&path/to/pre` when attempting to `pdflatex` from another directory, but that didn't seem to work.  What's the best way to do this?  If I am going to be using this `.fmt` file everywhere, is there some other strategy I should be thinking about? A logical place to install it in my tex system perhaps?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In texlive (and most likely other distributions) You can set TEXFORMATS in an environment variable or (better) your texmf.cnf to a list of places to look for format files.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Make that an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In texlive (and most likely other distributions) You can set TEXFORMATS in an environment variable or (better) your texmf.cnf to a list of places to look for format files.